# How can I extract the Date and Broker name from a list of files using powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a report based on the number of files being generated by I tool I developed. I'm using powershell in order to collect this information. There are about 10K+ plus of files with the same naming convention where I want to extract the queue name and count how many files were generated per queue for a give day.

Example of file syntax : `YYYY-MM-DD-B234.BBB.RandomQueue_[Broker-Name-BBBB]_UUID.txt`

Powershell script of what I have so far

```
$path =  'C:\DATA\MsgeAudit'
$result = Get-ChildItem $path -File | Select BaseName

$regex = '^(\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-)(((ActiveMQ|DLQ|Consumer| (B234.BBB.*))|B234.BBB).*?[^_]+(?=_))'
$Object = $result | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $regex } | ForEach-Object {
$Name , $Date = $_.BaseName.Split("-", 3)
[PsCustomObject] @{
    'Date' = $Date
    'Queue_Name' = $Name
    }
}
```

Here are the results I am getting after running code above with regex:

```
Date                                                                                       Queue_Name
----                                                                                       ----------
{02, 26-B234.BBB.OUTBOUNDS.GYH_[BBB-BMQ4-XXD0]_99e0e8f3-a309-4958-9358-a1fec6f3120e}        2021      
{02, 26-B234.BBB.OUTBOUNDS.GYH_[BBB-BMQ4-XXD0]_ec3eb4c0-66a4-4853-aa4e-26568378c0fb}        2021
{02, 26-B234.BBB.REPLAY.REQUEST_[BBB-BMQ2-YYC1]_0049d6c5-a401-4162-b512-99054b00f416}       2021      
{02, 26-B234.BBB.REPLAY.REQUEST_[BBB-BMQ2-YYC1]_055a85c0-c36b-4547-87b8-5328b85803ba}       2021      
{02, 26-B234.BBB.REPLAY.REQUEST_[BBB-BMQ2-YYC1]_066cb08e-1205-4423-8f1d-d1a495fda303}       2021
```

Expected results

```
Count  Queue_Name                DateModified
-----  -----------              ---------------
  2    B234.BBB.OUTBOUNDS.GYH     2021-02-26
  3    B234.BBB.REPLAY.REQUEST    2021-02-26
```

I've been at this for days and haven't been able to figure it out, I'm a beginner in powershell.

Comment: Add `gci 'C:\DATA\MsgeAudit' | Select BaseName` to question so we can test answers

Comment: @filimonic The change has been made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

```
# Test case data
$baseNames = @(
'2021-12-26-B234.BBB.OUTBOUNDS.GYH_[BBB-BMQ4-XXD0]_99e0e8f3-a309-4958-9358-a1fec6f3120e'
'2021-12-26-B234.BBB.OUTBOUNDS.GYH_[BBB-BMQ4-XXD0]_ec3eb4c0-66a4-4853-aa4e-26568378c0fb'
'2021-12-26-B234.BBB.REPLAY.REQUEST_[BBB-BMQ2-YYC1]_0049d6c5-a401-4162-b512-99054b00f416'
'2021-12-26-B234.BBB.REPLAY.REQUEST_[BBB-BMQ2-YYC1]_055a85c0-c36b-4547-87b8-5328b85803ba'
'2021-12-26-B234.BBB.REPLAY.REQUEST_[BBB-BMQ2-YYC1]_066cb08e-1205-4423-8f1d-d1a495fda303'
'2021-12-27-B235.BBB.REPLAY.REQUEST_[BBB-BMQ2-YYC1]_055a85c0-c36b-4547-87b8-5328b85803ba'
'2021-12-27-B236.BBB.REPLAY.REQUEST_[BBB-BMQ2-YYC1]_066cb08e-1205-4423-8f1d-d1a495fda303'
)

# Real-World usage data
# $baseNames = @([System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($path, '*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories) | 
#    % { [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_) })


$baseNames | 
    % { [PSCustomObject]@{
            Date = [DateTimeOffset]::ParseExact($_.Substring(0,10), 'yyyy-MM-dd', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture, [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::AssumeUniversal)
            QueueName = $_.Substring(11,$_.indexOf('_[') - 11)
        }
    } | 
    Group-Object -Property @('Date', 'QueueName') |
    % { [PSCustomObject]@{
            Count = $_.Count
            Date = $_.Group[0].Date
            QueueName = $_.Group[0].QueueName
        } 
    } |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

---

**Hint**: [Do not use RegExp](https://xkcd.com/1171/) unless you really have to.

**Hint**: Do not use `Get-ChildItem` on tons of files if you need **only** file names. `Get-ChildItem` makes additional query each file and huge additional job to get extra [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) information and make *(often)* excessive objects.

Comment: Thank you! I like your approach. For the queue name you starting the substring at position 11 and getting the end of it when it hits the underscore and first bracket. May I ask what does the modulus or `%` symbol doing?

Comment: `%` is alias for `ForEeach-Object`:  `Get-Alias -Name '%'`

Comment: Awesome, and how can I get rid of the time in Date object?

Comment: Replace `Date = [DateTimeOffset]::ParseExact($_.Substring(0,10).......` with `Date = $_.Substring(0,10)`, you'll then get result as string itstead of `DateTimeOffset` type.

Answer (score 2):

I like using the `-match` operator in concert with the automatic `$matches` variable for this kind of thing:

```
if($_.BaseName -match '^(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})-(?<queueName>[^_]+)_'){
    [PSCustomObject] @{
        'Date' = $Matches['date']
        'Queue_Name' = $Matches['queueName']
    }
}
```

On a successful `-match`, PowerShell will populate the `$Matches` variable with the named capture groups (`date` and `queueName`) from the pattern, and we can then extract those values.

Comment: thank you! So I understand, you created two properties which you embed in the regex so the regex engine will match each group in this case the date and queueName right?

Comment: @B.Allen I didn't create or embed anything, I just told the regex engine to [associate names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named_matched_subexpression) with parts of the pattern, these are also commonly referred to as "named captures"